# How to find an explicit formula for a function that is recursively defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, summation

So, I have this function that occurred in my calculation and I am finding a way to write it in a better way as non-recursive form, But I can't find a way how. Can anyone help in this thing?

$$
c_{m}(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}{ (c_{m-1}(i-1)i)}
$$
$$
c_{1}(n) = 1
$$
Here, $ n, m \in \mathbb{N} $

Your help would be appreciative.

Comment: What have you tried? I guess that this can be solve with Abel's transform :)

Comment: Would $c_m(0) = 0$ except of course for $m = 1$, where you declare it to be $1$?